# How To Create Screen Size Independent Android Applications

Tags: android, layout

I am working on android 2.2, I developed an application which is having an Image View and a button view.
In HVGA both the image and button are visible, but in QVGA I could see only the image. Rest of the buttons that are present under the image view is not visible.

How do I manage multi-screen resolutions in Android ?
Is there any thing like maintaining Aspect Ratio of the image to adjust the size as well maintain clarity.

I tried placing the buttons above the image view and it worked properly for HVGA and QVGA. 
Please let me know how can I handle the situation by placing the buttons below the image view.

I have done it in relative layout

Image width and height is fill_parent and wrap_content
Button width and height is wrap_content and wrap_content.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have enough space, either scale down your picture when you are on a smaller screen and use another folder with a different version of the layout and resources like that :

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml            // layout for normal screen size
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml      // layout for small screen size
res/drawable-ldpi/my_icon.png       // icon image for low density
```

Or you can put the all screen in a ScrollView and set the orientation vertical, which will offer the possibility to scroll the screen and access the button.

you can find ample information about dealing with [screen size management](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) here

Answer (score 1):

You should create different (xml) layout files for different screen sizes.

e.g. you could have your current one in `res/layout/my_layout.xml`, but one for small screens in `res/layout-small/my_layout.xml`.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more details.